# Linden leaf as dedication closure symbol

Tags: symbols, typography, fun

This is quite common phenomenon of 1950 to 1970 (proof?) books, at least in the Czechia region.

[image]
"To my wife"

It seems to me it represents linden tree leaf with bloom (?) which can be considered as national tree.

My questions are:

Is this class of (dedication) symbols named? Were these symbols created as ligatures and if answer is yes, can you provide link or some pics of them?

Is there any package for using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as *fleurons*, and one package containing fleurons is [`fourier-orns`](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/fourier-GUT/doc/latex/fourier/fourier-orns.pdf).

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\begin{document}
\centering
To my lovely wife.

\aldine
\end{document}
```

[image]

A number of other fleurons are provided in the package, which you can see listed in its documentation.